# DataFrame Returning Incorrect Value Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I create a dataframe called applesdf to show columns named id, item, price and location. My goal is to find the highest price of an apple with the same ID.

```
applesdf = {'ID': [1,1],
        'Item': ['Apple','Apple'],
        'Price': [2,1],
        'Location':[1001,1002]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(applesdf, columns = ['ID','Item','Price','Location'])

df
```

My dataframe:

| ID | Item | Price | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 2 | 1001 |
| 1 | Apple | 1 | 1002 |

So I run a groupby function to group the apples together and find the max price.

My code:

```
apples = df.groupby(['ID','Item'])
applesmax = apples.max()
applesmax
```

Result:

| ID | Item | Price | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 2 | 1002 |

The problem is my code is clearly returning the wrong location.

I'm aware that the groupby function is just reading the first location and just returning that location. I was wondering if there is a better function to use.

Comment: This has the same issue as your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68868224/15497888). `groupby max` will give you the maximal value _per columns_. Hence recieving the maximal value 2 for Price and maximal value 1002 for location.

Comment: Either of the solutions that were linked in your previous question would have worked. `applesmax = df.sort_values('Price').drop_duplicates(['ID', 'Item'], keep='last').sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: side comment: a DataFrame does not return anything. You may want to rephrase the title.

Comment: to retain full rows where `'Price'` takes its max, in each group of `['ID', 'Item']`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68876659/758174).

Comment: That sort values function works great, sorry for asking basically the same question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68877154/find-the-max-price-per-item-and-then-indicate-where-the-larger-pricer-was

Anyway to help me with this?